# d3js Tree square

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tree

I would like to use d3.js to build a pedigree tree.

All exemples that I found are showcasing organic trees.

[image]

Are there any exemples out there with a pedigree like style ?

[image]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could accomplish this using either the [cluster](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cluster.html) or [tree](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/tree.html) layouts. And using a custom path generator to draw orthogonal lines connecting nodes, as in this [elbow dendrogram](http://bl.ocks.org/2429963). I guess I was feeling inspired so I gave it a shot:

- http://bl.ocks.org/2966094

Comment: @mbostock - how would you add support for siblings? Let's say Robert Shanks and Elizabeth Shanks had another child?

Answer (score 18):

I recently created some [examples of using D3 to draw pedigrees](https://github.com/justincy/d3-pedigree-examples) in the style that most software does. There are examples for showing how to make it expand and collapse, transitions, and showing descendants as well as ancestors.

[image]