# Pedigree d3 with links

Tags: javascript, tree, d3.js

in answer [d3js Tree square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137238/d3js-tree-square) 
tell please how to upgrade this code then by clicking on the name of an ancestor go to url from json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use D3's [selection.on](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on) function on the `text` element created:

```
node.append("text")
  ...
  .on('click', function(d) {
    window.open('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + d.name);
  });
```

Here's an example:
**http://plnkr.co/edit/diAy00S3KvkkcAasriZ9?p=preview**

Comment: thank you! I try 
  'node.append("text")
      .attr("class", "name")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", -6)
   .style("cursor", "pointer")
   .on("click", function(d) {
  var link=d.url;
  if(link)
          window.open(link, '_blank').focus();
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });'

Comment: And it worked?  Or no?

Comment: it worked. yes!  But your variant is very elegant. I think you will also tell me how to show a picture (on the url) when hover name.