# How to get the vertically-oriented tree using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

The following url is going to get horizontally-oriented tree. 
My requirement is however to get a vertically-oriented tree using d3. 
Please suggest a proper valid solution for this requirement.

[d3js Tree square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137238/d3js-tree-square) 
[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3184089)?

Comment: i saw but i need tree like pedigree tree

Answer (score 9):

I know its been a while since you asked the question, but just in case I would like to bring to your attention a diagram that I made:

[image]

The code in on [codepen](http://codepen.io/VividD/pen/fIFJt). If you have any questions regarding the code, please let me know.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245751/how-do-you-create-a-family-tree-in-d3-js to get an extra 500 pts. Just read the comments of the question.

Comment: @VividD - how would you add support for siblings? Let's say Robert/Elizabeth Shanks had another child other than James. What I'm trying to achieve @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011999/how-can-i-prevent-overlapping-in-a-family-tree-based-on-familyecho

Answer (score 4):

change line 35, line 56 and elbow function to

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.about {
  fill: #777;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js?2.9.4"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 320, left: 0},
    width = 960- margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .separation(function(a, b) { return a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : .5; })
    .children(function(d) { return d.parents; })
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("tree.json", function(json) {
  var nodes = tree.nodes(json);

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(tree.links(nodes))
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", elbow);

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })

  node.append("text")
      .attr("class", "name")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", 8)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .attr("class", "about lifespan")
      .text(function(d) { return d.born + "–" + d.died; });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", 8)
      .attr("dy", "1.86em")
      .attr("class", "about location")
      .text(function(d) { return d.location; });
});

function elbow(d, i) {

  console.log(d)
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y
       + "V" + d.target.y + "H" + d.target.x 
       + (d.target.children ? "" : ("v" + margin.bottom))
}

</script>
</body>
```

this my result[image]

Comment: About halfway down the page is a good explanation of how to do this...  http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html